# Codeigniter 3 MY_Model database

Tags: codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde cada cliente vai ter seu banco de dados. Meu cenário então será: Cliente vai logar e através do ID dele aplicar a configuração do banco referente a esse cliente. Então além do banco de dados default, vai ter um segundo onde será relacionado a esse cliente, através do seu ID. Para que eu possa usar o ID da sessão pensei em criar uma `My_model` e colocar o segundo banco de dados ali e fazer um extends nas models que eu for utilizar esse segundo banco. Mas não estou conseguindo fazer, segue o código de como está. Agradeço quem puder me auxiliar.

```
<?php

class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{

protected $active_group;
protected $db2;  

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->connect();
}


public function __destruct() {

    $this->db->close();
}

public function connect($active_group = 'default'){

    $this->active_group = $active_group;
    $db = $this->load->database($active_group, TRUE);
    $this->db = $db;

     $db['second'] = array(
                             'dsn'   => '',
                             'hostname' => 'localhost',
                             'username' => 'root',
                             'password' => '',
                             'database' => 'nomedobanco',
                             'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
                             'dbprefix' => '',
                             'pconnect' => FALSE,
                             'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
                             'cache_on' => FALSE,
                             'cachedir' => '',
                             'char_set' => 'utf8',
                             'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
                             'swap_pre' => '',
                             'encrypt' => FALSE,
                             'compress' => FALSE,
                             'stricton' => FALSE,
                             'failover' => array(),
                             'save_queries' => TRUE
    );

      //$db2 = $this->load->database('second', TRUE);
    $this->db2 = $db;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verificando a [documentação](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html) do Codeigniter 3, a solução indicada por eles para criar conexões dinâmicas sem parâmetros pré-estabelecidos no arquivo `database.php`, seria usar a função `$this->load->database()` passando como parâmetro uma variável com valor **Data Source Name (DNS)**. Algo similar a isso:

```
$dsn = 'dbdriver://username:password@hostname/database';
$this->load->database($dsn);
```

Usando os parâmetros que você informou, seria algo assim:

```
<?php

class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{

    protected $active_group;
    protected $db2;  

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->connect();
    }


    public function __destruct() {

        $this->db->close();
    }

    public function connect($active_group = 'default'){

        $this->active_group = $active_group;
        $db = $this->load->database($active_group, TRUE);
        $this->db = $db;

        $dsn = 'mysqli://root:@localhost/nomedobanco';
        $this->db2 = $this->load->database($dsn);
    }

}
```

Comment: Fiz essas mudanças e apresenta erro como se não reconhecesse o banco de dados veja na minha resposta, tive que fazer separado pelo limite de caracteres

Comment: @ThiagoMoreira Qual exatamente a mensagem de erro apresentada pelo PHP?

Comment: Desculpa por ter feito errado a resposta, é que estou começando usar stack agora. O erro apresentado é esse: Message: Call to a member function select() on boolean 
vou te passar link do pastebin com parte do codigo  https://pastebin.com/dFGXETTf

Comment: O problema então está nos dados que você está informando para conexão. $this->load->database retorna provavelmente false (que é o tal boolean que ele está falando). Reveja se está correto o host, usuário, senha e nome do banco.

Comment: as configurações do banco estão corretas. Aí se eu colocar $this->db2 = $this->load->database( 'second', TRUE ); ele apresenta essa mensagem:  You have specified an invalid database connection group (second) in your config/database.php file. Mas no meu arquivo database.php é a conexão principal somente que eu quero e essa mensagem como se fosse ele atribuindo esse segundo banco no arquivo database

Comment: @ThiagoMoreira Reformulei a resposta. Dá uma olhada se te atende.

Comment: sim, atende dessa maneira!

Comment: @ThiagoMoreira Ótimo então. Se estive resolvido, pode aceitar a minha resposta.

Comment: ainda não consegui resolver